# Switch content from 1 element to next?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Say, I have 2 div elements (let div1 and div2) on a page. I'm fetching content dynamically. The content is text and I want the content to fill up the 2 div elements in such a way that when div1 runs out of space, the content is shown in div2. For an analogy, it's something like working on a notebook and whole surface of the notebook is the page, with div1 and div2 being left and right sides respectively. Once 1 side of the page is finished you move on to next and so on.

One of the ways could be splitting the text and setting a limit to the number of words for each div which will lead to going from div1 to 2 and so on.

I've looked at pagination and that is not something I'm looking for.

But is there a better way to accomplish this? Maybe like using the height attributes of the div element to trigger an event or something like that? Or any other suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the code from this example, which has 4  `div` elements with a fixed size, displayed side-by-side (see CSS), and which has all the text in the first `div`. The code will redistribute the text to the next `div`(s) as needed to avoid overflow:

```js
$(function() {
    // Take all words from first div and let them overflow into any next div
    var allwords = $('div.box').text().split(/\s+/);
    $('div.box').each(function (index, div)  {
        var text = '';
        var $div = $(div);
        var height = Math.round($div.height());
        allwords.slice().some(function (part, i) {
            $div.text(text + (i ? ' ': '') + part); // try, and see what we get
            // Detect overflow: when so, exit loop
            if ($div.prop('scrollHeight') > height) return true;
            text = $div.text();
            allwords.shift();
        });
        // Restore text to last non-overflowing text
        $div.text(text);
    });
});
```

```css
.box { width:100px; height:100px; border: 1px solid; display: inline-block; float: left }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer pellentesque dui ut nisl iaculis faucibus. 
Mauris non diam consectetur metus accumsan sollicitudin. Quisque ornare euismod mi.
</div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can detect when a div is overflowing with a function like this:

```
if (
    element.offsetHeight < element.scrollHeight
    || element.offsetWidth < element.scrollWidth
)
{
    // Overflow
}
else
{
    // No overflow
}
```

You can make a function that detach progressively pieces of content from the first div to the second one until overflow is gone.

Answer (score 0):

That's a weird solution but it works! I wouldn't recommend it for using it on a production website :P

```js
$(function() {
  
  function normalize() {
    
      $('#div2').text('');
      
      while ($('#div1')[0].scrollHeight > $('#div1')[0].clientHeight) {

      // get words of the text
      var words = $('#div1').text().split(' ');

      // get last word
      var lastWord = words.slice(-1);

      // pour it to div2
      $('#div2').text($('#div2').text() + lastWord);

      // remove it from the array
      words.length = words.length - 1;

      // and pour the rest back to div1
      $('#div1').text(words.join(' '));

    }
  }
  
  $('button').click(normalize);
  
  $('textarea').change(function() {
    $('#div1').text($('textarea').val());
  });
  
});
```

```css
#div1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
  word-break: break-all;
}

#div2 {
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>
  aaaa bbbb ccccccccc aaa bbb cccccccccccccc aa bbbbbb cccc aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbb ccccc aaaa bbb cccccccc aaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb ccccc
</textarea>
<button>normalize</button>
<hr>
<div id="div1">
  aaaa bbbb ccccccccc aaa bbb cccccccccccccc aa bbbbbb cccc aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbb ccccc aaaa bbb cccccccc aaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb ccccc
</div>
<div id="div2">

</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

i shall try a call back function, you can fade the first div and than call a function that fill the second:

```
           $(".div1").fadeOut(200,callbackFunction(){$(".div2").html("some text")});
```

Comment: But, I want both the div elements. I don't think you've understood my question completely

Comment: sorry, i can't help you.

Answer (score -4):

Also, you can fix the text limit of `textarea` like this `<textarea maxlength="50">`

That `50` can be replaced with any number. Even if you need dynamic lengths, you can use `JS` to do that.

Count the number of character using `JS`, once the limit is reached, switch the `focus` to other `textarea`.

`AngularJS` or any such MVC would be helpful to solve this easily.

Comment: But the op is asking for a notebook style system, How would you know whether he has reached the end of the "Page" (as the op puts it)

Comment: @ImmortalDude If the size of textarea and maxlength is fixed, there shouldn't be an issue to count the number of lines of text entered. Number of lines can be used to check end of the "Page".

Comment: The op is talking about divs and getting content remotely... It's like answering somewhere else really.